# Download Documents from Sharepoint RecycleBin

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, recycle-bin

Is there a way that i can download documents from Sharepoint Online  Recycle Bin using CSOM/PowerShell to a file share .Till now i have this where i am able to get the document details but i am not able to download the binary. Any suggestion will be appreciated **#SPO Client Object Model Context**

```
    $spoCtx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($sSiteCollectionUrl)  
        $spoCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($sUserName, $sPassword)   
        $spoCtx.Credentials = $spoCredentials  

        #SPO Site Collection 
        $spoSite = $spoCtx.Site 
        #Recycle Bin Content for the user 
        $spoRecycleBinItemCollection = $spoSite.RecycleBin 
        $spoCtx.Load($spoRecycleBinItemCollection) 
        $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery() 
        $spoRecycleBinItemCollection.GetEnumerator() | Export-CSV $exportPath
        foreach($spoRecycleBinItem in $spoRecycleBinItemCollection){ 
            if ($spoRecycleBinItem.ItemType -eq'File')
            { } //I was trying to do the Binary writer but its not working
```

Comment: If it's possible it's probably in that $spoRecycleBinItem. Can you spit out out the object's properties and see what you have to work with?

Comment: Hi ..Thank you i tried to use the Object properties but i couldn't see anything which will help in downloading the document

Comment: Hi, how about trying to a restore the file, download it from doc library and then remove it again?